# Moving subvarieties to avoid a certain point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

This seems like a problem that should be easy if true, but I wasn't able to prove it in general or disprove it. Given a complex projective variety $X$ and a sub-variety $Y$ and a closed point $p$ on $Y$. The question is: Is it possible to move $Y$ so it does not include the point $p$?
You can assume any form of positivity on $Y$. For example you can assume it is ample or a complete intersection.

By moving I mean the following: there is a continuous map $F: Y(\mathbb{C})\times [0,1] \rightarrow X(\mathbb{C})$, where $ F(-, 0)$ is the closed immersion of $Y$ in $X$. Furthermore the image of $F(-,1)$ does not include $p$. Moreover $F$ at any fixed time $t$ is an algebraic map ($F(-,t)$ is an algebraic map).

Another equivalent way of stating the problem is the following. Let's look at the connected component of the Hom scheme $\mathcal{H}om(Y,X)$ that contains the closed immersion of $Y$ into $X$. Is there another morphism in the same connected component that its image avoids $p$?

If untrue is there any general form for varieties $X$ that this holds?

I am interested in a very specific case where $X=\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{P}^r_{\mathbb{C}})$. $Y$ is a complete intersection that contains a diagonal element $p$ i.e. points with multiplicity $n$ of the symmetric product.

Comment: No in general: if you blow up a point in a (smooth) surface, the exceptional curve cannot move.

Comment: In the case when $X$ is singular, we do not expect to move divisors off singular points, e.g. in a quadric cone $xy = z^2$ lines making up the cone all pass through the singular point $0$ and there is no way to move them off it -- in the sense of linear equivalence, and probably in the sense you are asking as well.